# Alternate form for $\int e^{c q(x)+p(x)} dx$ where the constant $c$ is not within an integral

Tags: integration, exponential-function

Is there an alternate form for
\begin{equation}
\int e^{c q(x)+p(x)} \,\mathrm{d}x,
\end{equation}
where the constant $c$ is not within an integral?

I have tried rewriting the exponential as follows, and using integration by parts:

\begin{align}
I&=\int e^{c q(x)} e^{p(x)} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
I&=e^{c q(x)} \int e^{p(x)} \,\mathrm{d}x - c \int \left( q'(x) e^{c q(x)} \int e^{p(x)} \,\mathrm{d}x \right) \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}

However, I can't quite manage to find a form where there constant $c$ is not stuck inside the integral. (I am happy for everything else to be inside integrals.)

### EDIT:

For those wondering why I want to do this, here is some background:

I am trying to solve the following PDE using the method of characteristics:

\begin{equation}
    \left[ 2Dig c_{3} j(t) + c_{5} \right] \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + c_{3} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = u \left[ -ig c_{5} j(t) + c_{6} + Dg^2 c_{3} j(t)^2 - ig c_{3} j'(t) x \right] + c_{7} e^{-D g^2 \frac{t^3}{3}-igxt}
\end{equation}

PDEs of the form $P(x,t,u) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + Q(x,t,u) \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = R(x,t,u)$ can be solved using the method of characteristics by equating and solving any two of the following ODEs:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{P(x,t,u)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{Q(x,t,u)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{R(x,t,u)}
\end{equation}

If the constants introduced are given the labels $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$, then the method of characteristics requires that $\alpha_{1}$ be written as an arbitrary function of $\alpha_{2}$. e.g. $\alpha_{1} = F(\alpha_{2})$.

Finally, the form of the arbitrary function $F$ may be determined by differentiating the solution, and substituting back into the original equation.

In my case, I have taken 
\begin{align}
P(x,t,u) &= 2Dig c_{3} j(t) + c_{5} \\
Q(x,t,u) &= c_{3} \\
R(x,t,u) &= u \left[ -ig c_{5} j(t) + c_{6} + Dg^2 c_{3} j(t)^2 - ig c_{3} j'(t) x \right] + c_{7} e^{-D g^2 \frac{t^3}{3}-igxt}
\end{align}

First taking $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{P(x,t,u)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{Q(x,t,u)}$, I determined that
\begin{equation}
x = \left[ \alpha_{1} + c_{5}t + 2Digc_{3} \int j(t) \, \mathrm{d} t \right] \Big / c_{3}
\end{equation}
or, alternatively,
\begin{equation}
\alpha_{1} = c_{3}x - c_{5} t - 2Digc_{3} \int j(t) \,\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}

Second I took $\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{Q(x,t,u)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{R(x,t,u)}$ (Actually, in this case $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{R(x,t,u)}{Q(x,t,u)}$). Upon substituting $x = \left[ \alpha_{1} + c_{5}t + 2Digc_{3} \int j(t) \, \mathrm{d} t \right] \Big / c_{3}$ , this becomes a first order linear ODE:
\begin{align}
    c_3 \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t} - u \left[ -ig c_{5} j(t) + c_{6} + Dg^2 c_{3} j(t)^2 - ig c_{3} j'(t) x \right] &= c_{7} e^{-D g^2 \frac{t^3}{3}-igxt} \\
c_3 \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t} - u \left[ -ig c_{5} j(t) + c_{6} + Dg^2 c_{3} j(t)^2 - ig c_{3} j'(t) \left( \alpha_{1} + c_{5}t + 2Digc_{3} \int j(t) \, \mathrm{d} t \right) \Big / c_{3} \right] &= c_{7} e^{-D g^2 \frac{t^3}{3}-igt\left( \alpha_{1} + c_{5}t + 2Digc_{3} \int j(t) \, \mathrm{d} t \right) \big / c_{3}}
\end{align}

Now, when we solve this, using the integrating factor method for first order linear ODEs, which I will not do here, we gain a second constant $\alpha_{2}$.
Once all the integration is done, we can substitute $c_{3}x - c_{5} t - 2Digc_{3} \int j(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$ back in for $\alpha_{1}$. Note that there is no point performing this substitution before the integration is done, because there are unhelpful $x$ terms, and the integrations are all in terms of $t$.

In my case, this step is a little complicated, due to the arbitrary function $j(t)$. Due to this arbitrary function, the solution tends to remain in terms of integrals. However, if $\alpha_{1}$ is contained within any of the solution integrals, we can't finish the method of characteristics, because we can't substitute back for $\alpha_{1}$ until *after* the integration step. Hence my desire to help a constant escape from an integral.

I have managed to sneak the constant $\alpha_{1}$ outside of integrals at every point, except for one. To avoid clutter, the solution is essentially of the form
\begin{equation}
    u = e^{f(t)} e^{\alpha_{1} g(t)} \int e^{\alpha_{1} q(t)} e^{p(t)} \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
where $f(t), g(t), q(t), p(t)$ are messy functions of $t$.

If I can help $\alpha_{1}$ to escape the integral, then I can find a solution in terms of the arbitrary function $j(t)$. If I can't, then I will need to individually find solutions for particular forms of $j(t)$.

Comment: I don't really know what you're looking for. Including the constant $c$ doesn't really matter, because you could just roll it into the function $q$... and even if $c = 0$, there aren't generally good expressions for $\int e^{p(x)} \, dx$. What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: @user296602 I guess he's dealing with some $f(c)$ here.

Comment: I'm doing a very complicated integral which arose from using the method of characteristics. The constant $c$ is hiding the second variable from a function of two variables. (For instance, it could be $c=t+1$ Once the constant is removed from within the integrals, I can substitute back $t+1$ for $c$.)

Comment: @user296602 I have updated the question with significantly more background information. Does it answer your question?